# Material Design Lite - Portfolio Template - Adjusting Header Width

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

For this Material Design Lite site, I started with the base [Portfolio Template](https://getmdl.io/templates/portfolio/index.html).  I want to modify the header section in that I don’t want it to be the full width of the screen, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out which of the CSS classes to modify.

Here's the HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.pink-indigo.min.css" />

...

        <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--waterfall portfolio-header">
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row portfolio-logo-row">
                <span class="mdl-layout__title">
                    <div class="portfolio-logo"></div>
                    <!-- <span class="mdl-layout__title">Finishing Touch</span> -->
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row portfolio-navigation-row mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
                <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-typography--body-1-force-preferred-font">
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link is-active" href="about.html">About</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="products.html">Products</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="mdl-layout__drawer mdl-layout--small-screen-only">
            <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-typography--body-1-force-preferred-font">
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link is-active" href="about.html">About</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="products.html">Products</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```css
/*
.mdl-layout__header {
  width: 65%;
}
*/

/* Background image for header section above menu bar */
.portfolio-header {
  position: relative;

  background-image: url(../images/pink-polka-dot-header-bg.jpg); /* SFT */
}

.portfolio-header .mdl-layout__header-row {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.mdl-layout__title {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.is-compact .mdl-layout__title span {
  display: none;
}

/* Height for header section */
.portfolio-logo-row {
  min-height: 250px; /* SFT */
}

.is-compact .portfolio-logo-row {
  min-height: auto;
}

/* Main SFT Logo - large screen size */
.portfolio-logo {
  background: url(../images/sft-logo.png) 50% no-repeat; /* SFT */
  background-size: cover;
  /* height: 327px; /* SFT */
  /* width: 600px; /* SFT */
  height: 250px;  /* SFT */
  width: 469px;  /* SFT */
  margin: auto auto 10px;
}

/* Main SFT Logo - small screen size */
.is-compact .portfolio-logo {
  height: 79px;  /* SFT */
  width: 150px;  /* SFT */
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

I first tried adding a "width: 70%;" element to the .mdl-layout__header and .portfolio-header classes, but that didn't work.  It adjusted the width, however, the header then does not stay centered:

Without width element:
[Screenshot showing fullscreen width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXhe8.png)

With width element:
[Screenshot showing width element adjusted to 65%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muCNF.png)

I've tried playing around with the "position" element as well for both of those classes, however, none of them get the header to then center.  I'm kind of at a loss as to where to look next.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK  I figured this out with some help from a friend.  To the portfolio-header CSS class, I needed to add the following two lines to make it work:

```css
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

Everything now works!